# Most relaxed notion of decay at infinity

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am working on the analysis of certain time-dependent PDEs, where it is assumed that the equations admit sufficiently smooth solutions. Say that we are interested in $u(x,t)$ and $v(x,t)$, which solve a system of coupled PDEs in $\mathbb{R}^n \times (0,T)$.

At several junctions, I need to justify computations of the type:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} uv dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} [u \partial_t v+ v \partial_t u ]dx,
\end{equation}
or sufficient decay at infinity to ignore boundary terms, so that derivatives can be passed along:
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u \Delta v dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} v \Delta u dx.
\end{equation}

I understand that such arguments are perfectly valid, say, when $v$ has compact support. In this  case, some Dominated Convergence Theorem can be applied for the differentation, while a divergence-type theorem can be applied to a sufficiently large ball where boundary terms do not exist in order to handle derivatives.

The issue is that a priori, I do not have any good reason to impose the compact support restriction on any one of these functions. Therefore, I am wondering: **what is the most relaxed** (yet sensible and standard) **assumption of "decay at infinity" under which the above calculations can be rigorously justified?** Can this be done with, say, functions in the Schwartz space or functions satisfying some notion of exponential decay but with unbounded support? Any references or suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: What are the equations, in a nutshell, you’re using?

Comment: It also seems you could choose the $v$s to have finite support on arbitrary $[0, T]$, say infinitely smooth,  and use uniform bounds and density arguments to complete your estimates.